# Unexpected Output from Class Test

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Room {

    ArrayList<Bed> beds = new ArrayList<Bed>();

    private int BedNumber;

    public void createBed(boolean isDouble) {

        beds.add(new Bed(isDouble));

        BedNumber++;
    }

    public int howManyBeds() {
        return BedNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room p = new Room();
        p.createBed(true);
        p.createBed(false);
        Bed test = p.beds.get(0);
        System.out.println(test);
    }

}

public class Bed {

    private boolean isDouble;

    public Bed(boolean isDouble) {
        this.isDouble = isDouble;

    }

    public String bedSize() {

        if (isDouble) {
            return "Double Bed";
        } else {
            return "Single Bed";
        }
    }


}
```

When I compile it, Eclipse informs me that there are errors present in the code and asks me if I wish to proceed. When I do, I end up with a totally unexpected output - Bed@14ae5a5

I'm so confused as to what might be causing this. I imagine it's something stupidly simple but I'm just not seeing it.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

UPDATE ----

Found the error which I've corrected below. I was printing the object reference instead of calling a method...

This is now printing the correct result, however, Eclipse is still informing me that something is wrong at compilation.

Is my code badly written? Can anyone determine why Eclipse isn't happy?

Comment: Maybe it is taking from last successfully compiled class. You need to resolve all the compilation errors before attempting to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation errors are due to your attempt to declare two public classes in one Java file.

As for the output, you are attempting to print the Bed object--which results in Object.toString() being printed.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So, it prints the name of the class, "Bed," with an @ sign followed by the hex value of its hash, 14ae5a5.

Comment: All resolved now. The two classes are in separate files. 
On a totally different note, is it good practice to create a get method to retrieve values from an ArrayList outside a class?

Comment: For the sake of abstraction, yes. On a larger scale, this is to ensure that any changes can be done to a single function, and apply to all of its calls. It's much more difficult to, say for example, add platform-based ifdef guards to every single platform-dependent function call, rather than simply create a function with a different implementation per each platform, and call that each time.

Answer (score 0):

The `println` method of `System.out` actually calls the `toString` method of the parameter, in this case, a bed. However, `toString` is not present in your `Bed` class! So what did it do? It calls the `toString` method of `Object`, which returns `Bed@XXXX` where XXXX is the memory location of your bed.

To solve this, just add a `toString` method to your class. Remember to add `@Override` to overwrite the `toString` method of `Object`

```
@Override
public String toString () {
    //return a string representation here
}
```